# Is there a way to get the return value of a function and test it's "nonzero" at the same time?

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this:

```
if(func_cliche_start(line)):
   a=func_cliche_start(line)
   #... do stuff with 'a' and line here
elif(func_test_start(line)):
   a=func_test_start(line)
   #... do stuff with a and line here
elif(func_macro_start(line)):
   a=func_macro_start(line)
   #... do stuff with a and line here
...
```

Each of the func_blah_start functions either return None or a string (based on the input line).  I don't like the redundant call to func_blah_start as it seems like a waste (func_blah_start is "pure", so we can assume no side effects).  Is there a better idiom for this type of thing, or is there a better way to do it?

Perhaps I'm wrong, (my C is rusty), but I thought that you could do something this in C:

```
int a;
if(a=myfunc(input)){ /*do something with a and input here*/ }
```

is there a python equivalent?

Comment: @CppLearner -- The code above (other than my attempt at an example from C) is python.  What do you mean?

Comment: I deleted. I misread the C portion. My bad. But the equivalent is exactly what `garnertb` wrote. Even better, assuming the function explicitly returns something useful, `if my_fun:` testing TRUE / FALSE (1 vs 0, or None)

Comment: What's the nature of the code between the `if` and `elif` statements? Can it be encapsulated in functions? Or does it modify lots of variables in local scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function to make this work.

```
def assign(value, lst):
    lst[0] = value
    return value

a = [None]
if assign(func_cliche_start(line), a):
   #... do stuff with 'a[0]' and line here
elif assign(func_test_start(line), a):
   #...
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  It's not the most elegant, but it'll work.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't change the value of a.  Did either of you try this code??

Comment: @NedBatchelder, you're right, I didn't test it. Funny that it got so many votes. I'm fixing it but it gets even uglier.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I didn't test it either -- The idea was simple enough though.  Store the result in a mutable object inside a wrapper function.  Ultimately, what I might do is create a class which stores the function, override `__call__` to call the function and save the result in an attribute and then return the result.  Then that can be used as a decorator when I create the functions... `if func_cliche_start(line): a=func_cliche_start.result ...`

Comment: @mgilson, if I may, I would suggest creating a standalone method to call the function, rather than overriding `__call__`, because it makes it clearer that the resulting object has state that may change as a result of the call.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you assign the function func_cliche_start to variable a before the if statement?

```
a = func_cliche_start(line)
if a: 
   pass  # do stuff with 'a' and line here
```

The if statement will fail if func_cliche_start(line) returns None.

Comment: No, that's not what I want, because then I need to call func_cliche_start, func_macro_start, func_test_start all beforehand, and I'd prefer not to have to call these functions more than I have to.

Comment: What's the purpose of these functions. Look at your sample code. You have to call the same function again and again?

Comment: @mgilson, I'm not sure what you mean.  func_cliche_start would only be called once in my answer vs twice in yours.

Comment: @CppLearner It's for a text replacement/inclusion mechanism.  Based on a regex and the line from the file, I either include the block of text or include it.  Each function contains a regex that tells me if I want to include or not.  the string it returns is parsed from line and is also needed.

Comment: His solution only calls once. a is assigned to the return value of the function. and then check whether it s true or false. 0 and NOne are considered false. If you want to bind `a` to the function, you do this `a = func_cliche_start` don't make it callable.

Comment: @CppLearner I know his solution only calls once, but it would also have to call func_macro_start (which should be skipped if func_cliche_start is True)...

Comment: @mgilson you would make that call after the if statement...Sorry, I thought that was obvious.

Comment: What do these functions have common in? You probably want to refactor them, make a wrapper which tests some of the stuff, and then dispatch (depending on the circumstances). You can update your post with a brief pseudo code of those functions. Either way, whether you make calls to 4 functions depending on the conditions, or make one call to `my_super_function_tests_something` or not, you still have condition statements. You have to evaluate the true falseness !!

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop thru your processing functions that would be easier and less lines :), if you want to do something different in each case, wrap that in a function and call that e.g.

```
for func, proc in [(func_cliche_start, cliche_proc), (func_test_start, test_proc), (func_macro_start, macro_proc)]:
    a = func(line)
    if a:
        proc(a, line)
        break;
```

Comment: This ignores `#... do stuff with a and line here` lines

Comment: This would work if the stuff I was doing with a and line was the same in each case...close though...(Sorry, I wasn't extremely explicit about that in my question)

Comment: @mgilson I have simplified it further and now you can have different processing for each case

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put those blocks of code in functions. That way you can use a `dispatcher`-style approach. If you need to modify a lot of local state, use a class and methods. (If not, just use functions; but I'll assume the class case here.) So something like this:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

class LineHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
    def handle_cliche_start(self, line):
        # modify state
    def handle_test_start(self, line):
        # modify state
    def handle_macro_start(self, line):
        # modify state

line_handler = LineHandler(initial_state)
handlers = [line_handler.handle_cliche_start,
            line_handler.handle_test_start,
            line_handler.handle_macro_start]
tests = [func_cliche_start, 
         func_test_start, 
         func_macro_start]
handlers_tests = zip(handlers, tests)

for line in lines:
    handler_iter = ((h, t(line)) for h, t in handlers_tests)
    handler_filter = ((h, l) for h, l in handler_iter if l is not None)
    handler, line = next(handler_filter, (None, None))
    if handler:
        handler(line)
```

This is a bit more complex than your original code, but I think it compartmentalizes things in a much more scalable way. It does require you to maintain separate parallel lists of functions, but the payoff is that you can add as many as you want without having to write long `if` statements -- or calling your function twice! There are probably more sophisticated ways of organizing the above too -- this is really just a roughed-out example of what you could do. For example, you might be able to create a sorted container full of `(priority, test_func, handler_func)` tuples and iterate over it.

In any case, I think you should consider refactoring this long list of `if`/`elif` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a list of functions, make it a generator and return the first Truey one:

```
functions = [func_cliche_start, func_test_start, func_macro_start]
functions_gen = (f(line) for f in functions)
a = next((x for x in functions_gen if x), None)
```

*Still seems a little strange, but much less repetition.*

Comment: I kind of hoped the last line would be a little easier (something in itertools perhaps...).